# Mongoose.js check all fields to match a string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a proyect where the user can type in a searchbox whatever he wants to find from an user. It can be a name, a card ID, an username, etc.

Is there anything in mongoose.js to find in **all fields** a string?

Something like:

```
var user_input = "le";
Users.find({$contains: user_input}, function(error, usersFound){
    if(!error) console.log('I found users!', usersFound);

    //usersFound contains all the users that has "le" in at least one field 
});
```

I found already that there's an option that matches a RegEx but that's only for searching in one field.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  var user_input = new RegExp("le", 'i');
  var queryArray = [];

  for (var property in Users.schema.paths) {
    if (Users.schema.paths.hasOwnProperty(property)  && Users.schema.paths[property]["instance"] === "String") {
      queryArray.push(JSON.parse('{\"' + property + '\": \"' + user_input + "\"}"))
    }
  }

  var query = {
    $or: queryArray
  };

  Users.find(query, function(error, usersFound){
    if(!error) console.log('I found users!', usersFound);

    //usersFound contains all the users that has "le" in at least one field 
  });
```

Comment: This is weird, it returns me all the users in the database. :(

Comment: I changed a few things of how I constructed the query: there is a JSON.parse. I also added a condition on the "type" with property.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer you. I made only an edit to your answer. I added a RegExp to "user_input". But you answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: Great. You're welcome. Can you give me the regexp so that I can edit my answer and make it better for others ?

Comment: I just added *new RegExp(user_input,  'i')*. Before that it was just retrieving me the users that the complete field was ***le***. Now it matches "leo", "leader", etc. I dont have that "JSON.parse" maybe you should take it out.

Comment: Thx. Well. Maybe it's better if you write your own answer at the bottom of your question then :).